# Regret for deterministic algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, online-algorithms

I am learning the weighted majority algorithm in "foundation of machine learning" by Mohri. But I can not understand the conclusion from the book and other reference.

It has the statement

> No deterministic algorithm can achieve a regret $R_T = o(T)$ over all
> sequences.

How can we prove this? The book provide a scenario with two experts. But I think the statement is a general case, which can not be proved by the special case.

Meanwhile, in some reference
[course 1](https://people.seas.harvard.edu/%7Eyaron/AM221-S16/lecture_notes/AM221_lecture11.pdf) and  [course 2](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E15850/notes/lec15.pdf), they said

> Assume the number of mistakes the best expert makes is L ≤ T /2. Then,
> in the worst case, no deterministic algorithm can make fewer than 2L
> mistakes.

It is confused why the author also proves the general statement by using a special case. Is there any way to prove these two statements by using general cases?